# cd command doesn't work as desired inside a shell script

Tags: shell

I have lots of flac albums, each one in a single file and I want to split it in tracks. I can guarantee that there is only one flac file per folder with one cue file with the same name.

I wrote that:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
current=`pwd`
for d in `find . -name *.cue -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 dirname | sort --unique`
do
  cd \""$d"\"
  f=`ls *.cue`
  cuebreakpoints *.cue | shnsplit flac *.flac
  cuetag *.cue split*.flac
  rm ${f%.cue}.*
  cd \""$current"\"
done
unset IFS
```

As `find` command doesn't escape file names I changed the IFS to linebreaks. When I execute the script it fails in both `cd` lines saying that the route provided doesn't exists.

For example, suppose this file structure:

```
> Downloads
    split.sh
    > Music
        > FLAC
            > Goa Trance
                > Others
                    > (1997) Test Label - Album Name - Subtitle Of The Album
                        album test.flac
                        album test.cue
```

When I execute the script throws two errors (and other errors derived from the fact that the directory isn't changed):

```
./split.sh: line 6: cd: "./Music/FLAC/Goa Trance/Others/(1997) Test Label - Album Name - Subtitle Of The Album": No such file or directory
...
./split.sh: line 11: cd: "/Users/robotFive/Downloads": No such file or directory
```

But if I execute exactly this all works:

```
cd "./Music/FLAC/Goa Trance/Others/(1997) Test Label - Album Name - Subtitle Of The Album"
cd "/Users/robotFive/Downloads"
```

Do you know what could be happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one escape to much, change:

```
cd \""$d"\"
```

to:

```
cd "$d"
```

Comment: Thank you. I did my tests wrong and I arrived to the conclussion that the escaped quotes were necessary.